# Search for an area whose color changes slightly each time AutoIt

Tags: colors, ui-automation, autoit

I need to find the location of the green area like the [attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8ZCv.png). It changes position along the horizontal bar, it also changes color a bit, it's still green but different color code so I can't use PixelSearch

Comment: have you tried with shade variation? A value of 50 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used AutoIt Window tool to grab the baseline green color: 0x378620

Use this code to search an area for a similar color.

```
$shadeVariation = 10
$aCoord = PixelSearch(0, 0, 20, 300, 0x378620, $shadeVariation)
```